# Nullpointer Exception by FindViewById in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid, convertview

## Hey guys

today I started to develop my own little alarmclock app. But now I've got a problem, and I'm searching for three hours and couldn't solve it.

When I try to implement a listview with a custom design for each row, i get a NullPointerException, when I try to set the text from a textview in the layout. The reason for this exception is, that the findViewById-Call returns null and not the TextView I want to have.

On my search I found these two posts, but unfortunately they didn't help very well...

[Post1 - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057819/nullpointerexception-custom-listview-adapter)

[Post2 - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699422/android-listview-custom-items-nullpointerexception-findviewbyid-returns-null)

I'm using the same basic structure as in the two post above, but I'm unable to find the mistake...
Here is some code from my app:

The listitem_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

 <TextView
    android:name="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

  <TextView
    android:name="@+id/bottomtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

My Adapter:

```
public class AlarmClockArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {    
    private class ViewHolder {
    TextView headText;
    TextView subText;
   }


public AlarmClockArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, List<RowItem> objects) {
    super(context, layoutId, objects);
    this.mContext    = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutId;
    this.mListItems  = objects;
}


 /**    getView()
 * 
 *  ListView asks the Adapter for a view for each list item element 
 *  Override the getView()-Method to customize the ListView
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
                    // findViewById(...) returns Null 
        holder.headText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        holder.subText  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        convertView.setTag(holder);     
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    
    RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);
    
            // HERES THE NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
    holder.headText.setText(rowItem.getHeadText());
    holder.subText.setText(rowItem.getSubText());
    
    return convertView;
}
```

And at least the MainActivity, from where I instantiate the Adapter

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 public void initList() {

    //Adapter for the listview
    AlarmClockArrayAdapter mAdapter = new AlarmClockArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem_row, this.mListItems);
    
    final ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Any help would be great...
Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** check in

```
holder.headText.setText(rowItem.getHeadText());
```

exactly holder.headText return null

**2)** check in

```
if(convertView == null) {}
else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

executed first branch

**3)** usually I do like this:

```
// in constructor
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // context from Activity

public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
  }

  headText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
  subText  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to inflate layout without parent

Use this:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
```

Instead this:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
```

*Edit 1*

If this not help, try to inflate layout by id in getView()

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
```